# jQuery just refreshes page. - Trying to upload a file

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file, but I want to make sure it is the correct file type before sending it to my upload function. All that happens is a page refresh and I don't even get my alert box to show up for me.

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(openFile($('input#file').val()) == 1){
        window.alert("Upload Successful!");
        ajax_route(upload());
    }else{
        window.alert("Upload Failed!");
    }
    });

function ajax_route(action_requested){ 
$.post("upload_process.php", {action : action_requested}, function(data){
    if (data.length>0){ 
        alert("Hoorah! Completed the action requested: "+action_requested); 
    } 
});

function openFile(file) {
var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
if ($('input#select').val == 1){
switch(extension) {
    case 'csv':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}else if ($('input#select').val == 2){
switch(extension) {
    case 'xls':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}else{
switch(extension) {
    case 'doc':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
};
</script>
```

HTML form:

```
<div id="fileupload">
<form name="fileupload" id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="select" id="select" value="" style="display:none;">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

PHP upload function:

```
<?php
function upload(){
$select = $_POST["select"];

if($select == "1"){
    $path = "docs/tmtmasterdata.csv";
}elseif ($select == "2"){
    $path = "docs/A.2012_TMT_Vendor_Form.xls";
}elseif ($select == "3"){
    $path = "docs/z.Credit_Card_Authorization.doc";
}elseif ($select == "4"){
    $path = "docs/z.TMT_Customer_Credit_App.doc";
}

  if($_FILES['file'] != null){
    if(copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path)){
        ?><script>window.alert("Upload Successful!");</script><?php
    }else{
        ?><script>window.alert("Upload Failed!");</script><?php
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: you cannot upload files via ajax. standard work around: create a hidden iframe and do a normal form-based submission there.

Comment: I'm actually using a php function on a separate page to do the upload. I'm using the ajax to call the function without having the other page load.

Comment: do you also need a `event.stopPropagation()` as well as the default you have? `e.preventDefault().stopPropagation();`

Comment: Where is your `upload()` function?

Comment: I added the upload() function. It's on a separate page and I already know that it works. I had it working yesterday before I started to add all the jquery and ajax.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I tried adding that and it didn't work.

Comment: Another thought: instead of trying to reinvent the wheel: http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: @EricBrandel Not getting paid enough for this project. So I'm not spending money on that. My upload function works the way I want anyway. I just want to stop it from redirecting to that page.

Comment: @AaronLemon: That's fine, but there's no cost. "This plugin is open sourced under MIT license, GNU GPL 2 or later and GNU LGPL 2 or later." Just throwing out something to try if you're still pulling out your hair three hours from now.

Comment: @EricBrandel The links I had found for it redirected me to Paypal trying to charge me $9.

Comment: Sorry, try here: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader